# git-tfs clone not fetching all changesets

Tags: git, tfs

I am using git-tfs to clone all the changes from tfs into git.

In the tfs repo, there are 6 changesets ie (2000,2001,2002,3000,30001,3002)

When I run:

a) git-tfs clone --fetch-all  "http://tfs.web.xxx.com:8080/tfs/company" "$/Apps/branches/Build/Project/application"

It fetches only 2000,2001,2002. It is missing 3000,30001,3002.

b) git-tfs clone --fetch-all  "http://tfs.web.xxx.com:8080/tfs/company" "$/Apps/branches/Build/Project/application" -c=3000

It fetches only 3000,3001,3002.

Please advise how to fetch all.

Thanks,
B.

Comment: The issue is related to changeset 3000 has been deleted, the folder does not exist. So git-tfs has an issue with this. I tried using git-tf (gittf.codeplex.com/) instead and that was able to get all 6 changesets. This looks like a bug in git-tfs (https://github.com/git-tfs)